# My code gives me a NaN value when i add a var next to a number

Tags: javascript, var

NaN value appears in the console and i dont know why. What is wrong in my code?

```
var mass = 'kg';
var height = 'm';

var markMass = (45+mass);
console.log('Marks Mass is'+' '+markMass);

var johnMass = (67+mass);
console.log('John Mass is'+' '+johnMass);

var johnHeight = (1.60+height);
console.log('John height is'+' '+johnHeight);

var markHeight = (2.10+height);
console.log('Mark heigth is'+' '+markHeight);

var bmiJohn = johnMass / (johnHeight * johnHeight);
var bmiMark = markMass / (markHeight * markHeight);
console.log(bmiJohn, bmiMark);

var whoHasMore = bmiJohn > bmiMark;
console.log('has john a bigger bmi than mark?'+' '+whoHasMore);
```

java.js:124 45mass

java.js:127 67mass

java.js:130 1.6height

java.js:133 2.1height

java.js:137 NaN NaN

java.js:140 has john a bigger bmi than mark? false

Comment: Because they aren't integers. They are strings with kg or stuff.

Comment: `2.10 + "m" === "2.10m"` <- that is no longer a number.  Do calculations on the numbers and only display the units when you output the results.  Don't add them to the values.

Comment: `+` is addition if both arguments are numbers, otherwise it's concatenation. `*` is always multiplication, and it requires both arguments to be numbers. If either is not a number, it returns `NaN`.

Comment: You are making the number value a string appending the kg and the m (do this last in your outputs), it doesn't bite you until you perform and arithmetic operation (the division in your 5th part) it chokes.  NaN = Not A Number.  Treat the Variables as numbers by not appending your units to your numbers (converting them to strings).  Javascript does a lot of casting on the fly, it is part of the language you need to be very careful with.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript numbers are unitless. You seem to be trying to assign them units (`kg`, `m`). When you do `(45+mass)` the result is a string, because `mass` is a string and so `+` does string concatenation. Later, that string cannot be completely converted back to a number (because the `kg` has no numeric meaning), and so the conversion from string to number results in `NaN`.

Instead, just work with the numbers (see comments); add the units suffixes for display only:

```js
var mass = 'kg';
var height = 'm';

var markMass = 45; // *** Not (45+mass)
console.log('Marks Mass is'+' '+markMass+mass); // *** Add mass suffix here for display

var johnMass = 67; // ***
console.log('John Mass is'+' '+johnMass+mass); // ***

var johnHeight = 1.6; // ***
console.log('John height is'+' '+johnHeight+height); // ***

var markHeight = 2.1; // ***
console.log('Mark height is'+' '+markHeight+height);

var bmiJohn = johnMass / (johnHeight * johnHeight);
var bmiMark = markMass / (markHeight * markHeight);
console.log(bmiJohn, bmiMark);

var whoHasMore = bmiJohn > bmiMark;
console.log('has john a bigger bmi than mark?'+' '+whoHasMore);
```

---

Side notes:

- In `var x = (y + z);`, there's no purpose served by those `()` at all, just use `var x = y + z;`
- Trailing `0`s on the end of the fractional portion of a numeric literal don't do anything. `1.50` and `1.5` are exactly the same number. (You can put the `0`s there if you like, but it doesn't have any meaning in the code.)